# Runtime services no longer get injected into DNX console app (RC1)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, dnx

I used to be able to inject runtime services like `IApplicationEnvironment` into the constructor of the `Pogram` class of a DNX console application. However, using the latest CI build of RC1, the services no longer get injected:

```
public Program(IApplicationEnvironment env)
{
    if (env == null)
    {
        // env is null.
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(env));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNX platform wants to be compatible with regular `Program.Main` entry points. Therefore they removed dependency injection into the `Program` class.

In stead, you can use the new `PlatformServices` class which provides access to runtime services:

```
public Program()
{
    var env = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
}
```

The [`PlatformServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/PlatformServices.cs) class lives in the `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` namespace.

Types like `ILibraryExporter` and `ICompilerOptionsProvider` are now exposed through the [`CompilationServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.CompilationAbstractions/CompilationServices.cs) class in the `Microsoft.Extensions.CompilationAbstractions` namespace.

[> Reference](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113)